# Color code field in View?

Tags: views, rules

Use case:  When the Status is *Overdue*, the word overdue should display in red, and if it's *Accepted*, it should display as green.

I was hoping to use Rules to set this up, but don't see options to get this logic in.

[image: Screen capture]

Comment: Easiest option would be to rewrite the field with some wrapping HTML, use the Status token for the class. Then you can just change the colour with css

Comment: @Clive this should be answer, not a comment.

Comment: @NoSssweat - Just an opinion, but Clive's comment is not a complete answer, but a very broad possible direction, and is therefore more appropriate as a comment, rather than an incomplete answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use Style Settings in the field setting and and use replacement tokens as a css class.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with Format Table Settings.

[image]

Click on Format Table Settings And then enter the class with token in the row class option.

For example you can use something like 'status-[status]' and then write css for the class. Please make sure that status field is in the list of fields.

[image]